# How to improve successful question with no good answer?

Tags: discussion

I have managed to post a [question that has become quite successful](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18238/why-do-most-public-toilet-doors-open-inwards) but I am not satisfied with any of the answers. Even the most popular answer with over 75 upvotes does not really provide any data, sources or references, just unsubstantiated assumptions.

I was thinking about setting a bounty on on the question but I would like to explain why I am not satisfied with the current answers and what do I expect. Can I modify the original question to contain such explanation, maybe only temporary? I am afraid that just adding a comment under the question will get lost (not even shown on the first page of comments).

What does UX think?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, go ahead and update your question to indicate that you're looking for a different kind of answer. A bounty would be a great motivator now that activity around the question has cooled.

Comment: Won't I get punished by overacting moderators? :)

Comment: There is no problem if you're just adding to the question. (The only issue could be if you completely reword the whole question therefore invalidating a load of the answers). Keep the existing text but add to it explaining what you're looking for. I agree that a bounty is a great way to get extra attention to it - in fact that is one of the main purposes of bounties.